# How to name an array after content from a string

Tags: php, html, arrays, string

I've a form tag which sends the name for an array to a function but how can I name my array after this? Ok, code says more than thousand words:

```
<?php
function dynamic($id, $name, ... ){
...
        echo "<select id='$id' name='$name' size='...' multiple>";
...
        echo "<select id='$id' name='$name'>";
...
}
?>

<form ... method="post">
<p>
<?php
    echo dynamic("dynamic1", "choice1", ...);
?> 
</p>

<p>
<?php
    echo dynamic("dynamic2", "choice2", ...);
?> 
</p>

<p>
<?php
    echo dynamic("dynamic3", "choice3", ...);
?> 
</p>

<input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

I want to create a list where you can select multiple items but for this $name needs ot be an array. The array should named like the second variable. In one case it should be named choice1 in another choice2

Like how do I get from `$name = "choice1";` to `choice1[]`

@edit Added a new line in function to show my problem. somtimes $name needs to be and array and sometimes not

Any ideas?

Comment: `echo dynamic("dynamic2", "choice2[]", ...);`?

Comment: `echo "<select name='{$name}[]' ...";`?

Comment: Do you want `echo "<select id='" . $id . "' name='". $name . "[]' size='...' multiple>";` ?

Comment: So how you gonna decide when it needs to be an array and when not?

Comment: in `echo "<select id='$id' name='$name' size='...' multiple>";` it need to be an array or to mark the multi choice in `echo "<select id='$id' name='$name'>";` it just need to be a normal variable

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to use dynamic variable names, which is possible in PHP, but you need to be careful with this. Production code using this can be difficult to maintain and throw errors quite easily.

Anyway, lets say you have a value in the form $_POST that you want to use as a variable name. You would do so like this.

```
$id = "gettheidsomewhere";
${$id}[] = "whatever";
```

Like i said, use this carefully. Dynamic variable names are dangerous and very hard to debug when things break.

If you do not know the value used for $id, then you will need to loop through your post variables and assign them accordingly. I would assume you want to add some extra logic, but here is a basic example.

Using a key value loop you can obtain the name of the post variable, stored as $key and the value. So for $_POST["something"] = "test", when this line is looped over, $key will be "something" and $value will be "test".

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    ${$key}[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: edited my question!
how do I get from `$name = "choice1";` to `choice1[]`

Comment: @DrS So… add a `"[]"` to the string…!?

Comment: I have added some additonal code to help you. You will need to use a key value loop and build the variables this way. You may want to enhance it a bit so it doesnt convert everything to an array, but this will do what you need